# Checkmark changes after scrolling in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

No matter what I do I cannot keep the checkmark item selected after scrolling. I know this has to do with the fact that the cells are reused when items are visible but I'm not sure how to handle this.

The following code successfully shows the right item selected on the first load, the issue is that once I start scrolling it randomly keeps selecting other items.

What is the proper way to keep the selected item after scrolling and prevent from selecting unwanted items/rows?

```
class CategoriesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { 
    var categories: Results<Category>! // I'm getting this from the Realm data base 
    var categoryTracker:Category? // I'm getting this from other view controler
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoriesCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesCell
        
        let categoryList = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.labelCategoryName.text = categoryList.categoryName

        if categories[indexPath.row].categoryID == self.categoryTracker!.categoryID{
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        // show checkmark on category for selected item and uncheck the rest
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: indexPath.section)) {
                cell.accessoryType = row == indexPath.row ? .checkmark : .none
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Images:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. This happens because **when a cell with .checkmark is reused, it is not reseting its accessory type back to .none**

You should update your:

```
if categories[indexPath.row].categoryID == self.categoryTracker!.categoryID{
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
```

to:

```
if categories[indexPath.row].categoryID == self.categoryTracker!.categoryID {
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be working fine, for some reason I thought I would need to keep track of the selected item. Thanks a lot!